# Magento: How to read directly from Magento database

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

I'm trying to read directly from the Magento database through a custom script that looks like this:

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
echo var_dump($conn);

function getAitocAttr() {
    $test = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM customer_entity");
    var_dump($test);
}

getAitocAttr();
```

Nothing is showing up when I run this script. What am I doing wrong? The error I'm receiving is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your error message

> Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

PHP is complaining about a method call to `fetchAll` on a non-object.  Looking at your code, the only place you call `fetchAll` is here.

```
function getAitocAttr() {
    $test = $conn->fetchAll("SELECT * FROM customer_entity");
    var_dump($test);
}
```

Within the `getAitocAttr` function there's no `$conn` variable defined.  When you say

```
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
```

you've defined `$conn` **outside** the scope of the `getAitocAttr` function.  You'll need to either define `$conn` inside `getAitocAttr`, or declare `$conn` as global inside `getAitocAttr` for this to work.

Comment: Yeah! Figured this out myself as well :)Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem with your script is exactly. It looks OK however I have tackled the problem slightly differently to this and it works for me.

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);
$conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
echo var_dump($conn);

function getAitocAttr()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer_entity";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    echo "<pre>";
    while ($row = $readresult->fetch()) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}

getAitocAttr();
```

Comment: Hmm...this doesn't work for me either. That is strange...any ideas why?

Comment: oh i didn't notice the `echo var_dump($conn)` line. your script may just be dying silently. remove the line with `echo var_dump()`

Comment: Ok, I did and turned on error handling. I'm getting Fatal error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on a non-object

Comment: that could mean that your connection isn't being established with the db. try 'core_write' instead of 'core_read'?

Comment: "core_write" doesn't work either. My var_dump($conn) seems to look ok. So I guess there is a connection established?

Comment: So when I added the whole $conn = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read'); inside the function it works...Don't understand why, but it does! :)